# How can I listen to a variable change and display on the screen

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-remote-config

I'm building a mini-cypto app in flutter which requires me to allow the user calculate the worth of coin they want to buy. I use Firebase Remote Config for getting the current worth of the coin.
This is a simple aritimetic

```
coinRate = 0.15

usdRate = 1

usersInput = 20

usersInput * usdRate / coinRate = 133.3333
```

So my issue now is now to display the answer on the screen.
Below is the code.

```
class CoinPlaceHolder extends StatefulWidget {
 const CoinPlaceHolder({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

 @override
  State<CoinPlaceHolder> createState() => _CoinPlaceHolderState();
  }

 class _CoinPlaceHolderState extends State<CoinPlaceHolder> {
  @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  home: FutureBuilder<FirebaseRemoteConfig>(
    future: setupRemoteConfig(),
    builder: (BuildContext context,
        AsyncSnapshot<FirebaseRemoteConfig> snapshot) {
      return snapshot.hasData
          ? BuyCoin(remoteConfig: snapshot.requireData)
          : const Scaffold(
              body: Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                  color: Colors.black26,
                ),
              ),
            );
         },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The code above is to make connection to the firebase remote config.

```
Future<FirebaseRemoteConfig> setupRemoteConfig() async {
 final FirebaseRemoteConfig remoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.instance;
  await remoteConfig.fetch();
   await remoteConfig.activate();

   return remoteConfig;
 }
```

The below code is to collect the data from the user

```
class BuyCoin extends AnimatedWidget {
  final FirebaseRemoteConfig remoteConfig;
   BuyCoin({Key? key, required this.remoteConfig})
  : super(key: key, listenable: remoteConfig);

  final TextEditingController _coinWorth = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _luwiWorth = TextEditingController();

  dynamic usdtRate;
  dynamic luwiRate;
  dynamic finalRate;
  dynamic finalData;

  rateCalculator(finalData) {
  usdtRate = 1;
   luwiRate = remoteConfig.getDouble('LUWI');
   var luwiCal = usdtRate * double.parse(_coinWorth.text);
   finalRate = luwiCal / luwiRate;
   }
 }
```

So inside my build context I have a TextFormFeild

```
 TextFormField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
     controller: _coinWorth,
       decoration: const InputDecoration(
         labelText: 'Enter coin worth'),
          ),
```

And I also have a Text field for display the calculated worth.

```
 Text(`$finalRate`)
```

But all means as not been working...
So please what can I do to make is work
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use [ValueNotifier](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ValueNotifier-class.html)? you can add listener to it. Or use `ValueListenableBuilder` in your widget tree and set this `ValueNotifier` for `valueListenable` field.

Comment: Alright I will try the ValueListenBuilder because I have used the ValueNotifier still not getting the result... or probably I was implementing it in a wrong way.
Thanks. 
I will revert back.